# Rails Habtm with a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Is that possible to have a field in a **has and belongs to many** table?

Just like favorite:

```
create_table :messages_users, :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer :message_id, :null => false
  t.integer :user_id, :null => false

  t.boolean :favorite, :null => false

  t.timestamps
end
```

I saw timestamps works well, thanks to ActiveRecord.  But when I try to add favorite into the table and then I try:

```
Message.first.users << User.first
```

Then I get this error message:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   SQLite3::SQLException:
>   messages_users.favorite may not be
>   NULL: INSERT INTO "messages_users"
>   ("created_at", "message_id",
>   "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES
>   ('''2010-05-27 06:07
>   :50.721512''', 1, '''2010-05-27 
>   06:07:50.721512''', 1)

I would like to use a habtm, I don't like has_many foo though bar association :)

Is that possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible.
Use `has_many foo though bar`.

Comment: If you want a comparison between habtm and has_many :through

this is the [right place to start][1].

The blog has many other articles on has_many :through which I encourage you to dig into.

Basically clyfe is right and I don't understand why you would prefer habtm when it's not created with the scope you are trying to achieve.

Switch to has_many :through and you'll be amazed at how flexible it is once you get to know how it works.


  [1]: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/2/28/association-goodness

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I think I will use has_many :through :(